# Magento 2: How to add less file that will have effect on installed Extension?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Basically I have developed extension.

Now I am finding by which user of extension can add styling using less that have effects on extension?

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: donot understand what you trying to achieve

Comment: Basically i have developed an Extension which soon i upload on marketplace.In that extension i want to include a less file by which user can change the css which the extension displayed.

Comment: e.g if you have install my extension you got a less file in it by which u can write css into it to change its styling.